# In LWC is there a way to Save selected Radio Button value to a record

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable, lightning-recordeditform

My requirement is to display picklist values as radio buttons in a Lightning record edit form, but I am unable to save the values selected from the radio buttons to the record. Default save button of record edit form doesn't work for radio group. Is there a way to save the selected radio group value to a record?

Thanks!

HTML - The Lightning input field is the picklist that I'm rendering through radio group.

```html
        <lightning-record-edit-form class="slds-text-body_small" record-id={recordId} object-api-name={ObjectAPI}
            onsuccess={handleSuccess} onerror={handleError}>

            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

            <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                <div class="slds-text-body_small">
                    <h1>Description of Worksearch Circumstances
                    </h1>
                </div>
    
                <lightning-radio-group class="test" options={options} onchange={handleChange} value={value} type="radio">
                </lightning-radio-group>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-p-around_medium ">

                <label class="slds-text-body_regular slds-text-color_default " for="worksearch">Description of worksearch circumstances

                </label>
                <div class="slds-p-top_x-small">
                    <lightning-input-field type="" id="worksearch" field-name={workSearchFeild}
                        variant="label-hidden">
                    </lightning-input-field>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Getting picklist as radio -

```javascript
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: FACT_NAME })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: WORK_SEARCH
    }) wiredPicklistValues({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.options = data.values;
            console.log('data.values>> ' + JSON.stringify(data.values));
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            console.log('error>> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            this.options = undefined;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When do you want to save? upon radio value selection or upon some button click?

Comment: On save buttn click. Basically I've rendered picklist as radio button group in record edit form, as picklist values are bit long. But Radio group are not supported in REcord edit forms. so im trying figure some way out.

Comment: You can build custom LWC component to edit as shown in the example below.

Comment: is it possible to dynamically place the selected value of radio button to the picklist feild use default save button of record edit form to save the record.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that.

Comment: I guess i need to create a custom form instead of record edit form. then i can use radio group set and use apex class to update the record.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-radio-group/example),

```html
<template>
    <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
                          label="Radio Group"
                          options={options}
                          value={value}
                          type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class RadioGroupBasic extends LightningElement {
    value = '';

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'Sales', value: 'option1' },
            { label: 'Force', value: 'option2' },
        ];
    }
}
```

When user selects a radio, selected value will be stored in `value` prop. If you have stored the record id in separate prop for ex., `recordId`, then you can call server controller passing the recordId and value to update it.